# a valid element not in np.arange, though print() does show it, dtypes are also same

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = 1.25
if a in np.arange(1,2,0.05):
    print(a)
```

but this if condition doesn't holds true,though

```
print(np.arange(1,2,0.05))
[ 1.   1.05  1.1   1.15  1.2   1.25  1.3   1.35  1.4   1.45  1.5   1.55   1.6   1.65  1.7   1.75  1.8   1.85  1.9   1.95]
```

does have 1.25 in it.

I read that arange is not really consistent, but is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there is no `1.25` in that range it's actually `1.2500000000000002` and that's because numpy considers a double precision float for float numbers by default and in cases that decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly as binary fractions, they can hold the more accurate value for floats. And what you see in print result is just a formatted representation of the real value.

```
In [58]: l = np.arange(1,2,0.05)

In [59]: l[5]
Out[59]: 1.2500000000000002

In [60]: type(l[5])
Out[60]: numpy.float64
```

One way for solving that is casting the type to `float32`:

```
In [61]: l = np.arange(1,2,0.05).astype(np.float32)

In [62]: a = 1.25

In [63]: type(a)
Out[63]: float

In [64]: a in l
Out[64]: True
```

Comment: *"decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly as binary fractions"* - that's equally true for the literal `1.25` that the values in the array are being compared to (which will also be a 64 bit float). I think the issue is that the *step size* can't be represented exactly as a binary fraction. For example, `1.25 in np.arange(1, 2, 2**-4) == True`.

Comment: @ali_m Yes, thanks for clarify but as I said it's `decimal fractions`, and it occurs after adding the step, and the reason might be the step or the result.

Answer (score 0):

Using `item` to print values in full splendor:

```
In [83]: for i in np.arange(1,2,0.05):print(i.item())
1.0
1.05
1.1
1.1500000000000001
1.2000000000000002
1.2500000000000002
1.3000000000000003
1.3500000000000003
1.4000000000000004
1.4500000000000004
1.5000000000000004
1.5500000000000005
1.6000000000000005
1.6500000000000006
1.7000000000000006
1.7500000000000007
1.8000000000000007
1.8500000000000008
1.9000000000000008
1.9500000000000008
```

Even `linspace` has those extra digits off at the end:

```
In [84]: for i in np.linspace(1,2,21):print(i.item())
1.0
1.05
1.1
1.15
1.2
1.25
1.3
1.35
1.4
1.45
1.5
1.55
1.6
1.65
1.7000000000000002
1.75
1.8
1.85
1.9
1.9500000000000002
2.0
```

`in` and `==` tests are not a good idea when working with floats.

`isclose` and `allclose` test for small differences rather than exact match

```
In [89]: np.isclose(np.arange(1,2,0.05),1.25)
Out[89]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False], dtype=bool)
In [90]: np.isclose(np.arange(1,2,0.05),1.25).any()
Out[90]: True
```

Look at the `isclose` code to see all that is involved in comparing floats.